# Select all Items which intersect

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml, intersect

I would like to get all values which Intersect from this LINQ query:

```
Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).Intersect(myList).Any();
```

I don't know how to add a select.

Comment: Assuming the Where is being applied to a collection of `T` do want your result to be a collection of `T` or a collection of the type of `T.Attribute("name").Value`?

Comment: @BobVale a Collection of `T.Attribute("name").Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the you want all the Attribute("name").Value that are in myList

You can either do

```
Where(x=>myList.Contains(x.Attribute("name").Value)).Select(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value)
```

or

```
Select(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value).Intersect(myList)
```

Comment: The second answer gets and error: _Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<System.Xml.Linq.XElement,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type._ Is there any solution because it seems a easier solution. (First works)

Comment: @kmxillo I did a typo, missed the `x=>`.  I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do intersection? Why don't just List.Contains?

```
data.Where(x => myList.Contains(x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
```

or

```
data.Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).Intersect(myList);
```

Comment: x is XElement. How can convert to List<string> because .Value returns String.

Comment: Sorry but You miss one parentesis. And that solution does not work,

Comment: @kmxillo: Silly mistake due a hurry. That was a copy-paste. Fixed it now.